# Multiple frames with tkinter - How to make them run on fullscreen mode

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter

I wrote a code using tkinter to switch between frames after a few seconds.
The problem is: All the application must run in fullscreen.

Here is the code.

```
from tkinter import *


N_TRIALS = 3
COUNT=-2
N_INTERVALS = 2*N_TRIALS + 1
RELAXING_TIME = 2000
RESTING_TIME = 2000
TASKING_TIME = 2000
start_btn_state = False

def raise_frame(frame):
    frame.tkraise()
    global COUNT
    COUNT+=1
    print(COUNT)

    if (frame == f3 and COUNT==N_INTERVALS):
        frame.after(RESTING_TIME,lambda:raise_frame(f5)) 
    elif(frame == f5):
        frame.after(RELAXING_TIME,lambda:raise_frame(f6)) 
    elif frame == f2: 
                frame.after(RELAXING_TIME, lambda:raise_frame(f3)) 
    elif frame == f3: 
                frame.after(RESTING_TIME, lambda:raise_frame(f4))
    elif frame == f4: 
                 frame.after(TASKING_TIME, lambda:raise_frame(f3))
    elif frame==f6:
        root.destroy()           


def finish():
    root.destroy()

def start():
    start_btn_state=True
    raise_frame(f2)


root = Tk()

f1 = Frame(root)
f2 = Frame(root)
f3 = Frame(root)
f4 = Frame(root)
f5 = Frame(root)
f6 = Frame(root)

for frame in (f1, f2, f3, f4, f5,f6):
   frame.grid(row = 0, column = 0, sticky='nsew')

lb0=Label(f1, text="blablabla",font=("Arial Bold",10))
lb0.pack(padx = 10, pady=10)
lb1=Label(f1, text="blablabla",font = ("Arial Bold",10),fg = "black")
lb1.pack(padx = 10, pady=10)
lb2 = Label(f1, text="blablabla",font = ("Arial Bold",10),fg = "green")
lb2.pack(padx = 10, pady=10)
lb3 = Label(f1, text="blablabla",font = ("Arial Bold",10),fg = "blue") 
lb3.pack(padx = 10, pady=10)
lb4 = Label(f1, text="blablabla",font = ("Arial Bold",10),fg = "red")
lb4.pack(padx = 10, pady=10)

start_value=BooleanVar()
btn_start=Button(f1, text="Start",font = ("Arial Bold",20), command = start)
btn_start.pack(padx=10,pady=30)

close_value=BooleanVar()
btn_close=Button(f1, text="CLOSE",font = ("Arial Bold",20), command=finish)
btn_close.pack(padx=10,pady=30)

Label(f2, text='ACTION 1').pack()
#Button(f2, text='Go to frame 3', command=lambda:raise_frame(f1)).pack()
f2.config(bg='red')


Label(f3, text='ACTION2').pack(side='left')
f3.config(bg='green')

Label(f4, text='ACTION3').pack()
f4.config(bg='blue')


Label(f5, text='RELAXING FINAL').pack()
f5.config(bg='black')


raise_frame(f1)
root.mainloop()
```

I don't know how to expand the frames to fill all the window. I tried everything: geometry, width and height, etc. It seems probably (100% sure) that I am doing something wrong to put those frames on fullscreen.

could anyone help me?

Sorry about the code that is not in OOP. I am learning about it.

I appreciate the help!

Best Regards

Comment: Please try to reducce this code down to a [mcve]. We don't need all of the comments, and if the problem is with a frame expanding to full screen, we only need one or two frames to illustrate the problem.

Comment: @BryanOakley Sure. Sorry about that.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The placement and geometry of a window on screen is controlled by the window manager. Your application provides information about its size but the window manager is what decides which windows are visible and where they get placed. For this reason the flag that controls if a Tk window is fullscreen or not is one of the [wm_attributes](https://www.tcl.tk/man/tcl/TkCmd/wm.htm#M10) flags.

You can set your toplevel window to fullscreen using `root.wm_attributes('-fullscreen', 1)`. If your frames are then managed such that they expand to fill the parent toplevel then they will fill the screen. For that with your grid usage you should configure the root grid geometry manager to allow (0,0) to expand to fill the area:

```
root.grid_rowconfigure(0, weight=1)
root.grid_columnconfigure(0, weight=1)
```

Or you could place each frame here at 0,0 and fill the available space using:

```
frame.place(x=0, y=0, relwidth=1.0, relheight=1.0)
```

This is one situation where `place` might be appropriate over `grid`.